# how do I make a page that shows specific items in the database when the item is clicked

Tags: php

I am making an eccommerce website. my page is filled with images of items for sale and details of the item under the image. I also have a button under the image so that when clicked the user can view more information on this item. But I don't know how to do this. Below is the code I have that displays the information and images from database.

```
<?php
// Default query for this page:
$q = "SELECT * FROM item";


// Create the table head:

echo '

';

// Display all the items, linked to URLs:
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 $directory = '/uploads';
 $file= $row['image_name'];

    // Display each record:
    echo "

     <div class='col-lg-3'>
        <image src=$directory/$file title='$row[image_name]'  width='213' height='200'></br></br>
    <p align='left'> Brand : {$row['brand']}</br> Type: {$row['category']} </br> Price : £{$row['price']}  </p>
     <a class='btn btn-primary'  href='showitem.php' role='button'>More Details &raquo;</a>
    </br></br></br>
     </div>

 ";
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
mysqli_close($dbc);



?>
```

Comment: each item needs a unique identifier, then you can pass your item into a GET `showitem.php?item=1234` and on that page create code to select * from table where item=1234 etc

Comment: in the database each item does have a unique id . have you any idea of the code needed on the showitem.php page?

Comment: You are already bringing everything on the table... is the"more information" in other table(s)? if not, just display it and hide the content with CSS (class) then the button will just toggle the CSS (class)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need unique id in table then Pass your product id in url like `showitems.php?pid=1` and make a query with where condition pid get from url.

```
  SELECT * FROM item WHERE  id = "$_GET['pid']"
```

Comment: how do i then output the details on the page?

Comment: Is ur detail any other table ? @dgly6

Answer (score 2):

What about adding the identifier into the link of your button like this:

```
<a class='btn btn-primary'  href='showitem.php?item={$row['id']}' role='button'>More Details &raquo;</a>
```

And then you can generate detailed product description with showitem.php, using $_GET['item']

Comment: this brings up the correct id in the url but then how to i get the information of the item onto the page ?

Comment: Do you want the product description to be placed on the same page? Please list the field names of the table 'item'.

Comment: category, title, brand, description,  price .. i want all these to be placed on the next page aswell as the image.

Comment: has anyone any idea?

Comment: Knowing the table structure is a key to solve your issue here. The page showitem.php is even more simple than the one you showed:
<?php
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, $_GET['item']);
$q = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE id='$id'";//presuming the table item there is id field
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
$directory = '/uploads';
$file= $row['image_name'];
echo "
<image src=$directory/$file title='$row[image_name]'>
<p> Brand : {$row['brand']}</br> Type: {$row['category']} Price : £{$row['price']}
Description : {$row['description']}
 ";

?>

Comment: wrap the output above into html properly, since the comment cap made me remove it from the code.